# Formatting Date in Generate Statement

Tags: apache-pig

In Pig, I have a statement which basically appends the date to my generated values.

```
Data = FOREACH Input GENERATE (CurrentTime()),FLATTEN(group), COUNT(guid)oas Cnt;
```

The output gives me the date `2013-05-25T09:01:38.914-04:00` in ISO8601.

How can I make this just as `"YYYY-MM-DD"` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have several options:

Convert it with Pig functions :

E.g:

```
A = load ...
B = foreach A {
  currTime = CurrentTime();
  year = (chararray)GetYear(currTime);
  month = (chararray)GetMonth(currTime);
  day = (chararray)GetDay(currTime);
  generate CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(year, '-'), CONCAT(month, '-')),day) as myDate;
}
```

OR pass the date to the script as a parameter:

```
pig -f script.pig -param CURR_DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

OR declare it in script:

```
%declare CURR_DATE `date +%Y-%m-%d`;
```

Then refer to the variable as `'$CURR_DATE'` in the script.

You may also create a *modified* CurrentTime UDF in which you convert the DateTime object to the appropriate format with the [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.

The easiest would be to declare the date in the beginning of the script.

Comment: Hey Lorand,Thanks for the reply. I had in fact tried the  passing the date as a parameter method. But the final output for today shows 1983 instead of 2013-05-25. Any idea why? The same output parameter works fine while assigning it to the name of the stored file. For example:  STORE Output INTO 'Outputs$CURR_DATE works fine and shows as Output2013-05-25.

Comment: It's because if you do the substraction: 2013-5-25 you'll get 1983. That's why I used quotes (`'$CURR_DATE'`) so that it will be handled as chararray instead of int.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Pig 0.12 or later, you can use
ToString(CurrentTime(),'yyyy-MM-dd')

You can use any datetime type instead of CurrentTime()

Refer to http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string for date time formats.