# Pig - How to cast datetime to chararray

Tags: apache-pig

I'm using CurrentTime(), which is a datetime data type. However, I need it as a chararray. I have the following:

```
A = LOAD ...
B = FOREACH A GENERATE CurrentTime() AS todaysDate;
```

I've tried various approaches, such as the following:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (chararray)CurrentTime() AS todaysDate;
```

However, I always get ERROR 1052: Cannot cast datetime to chararray.

Anyone know how I can do this? By the way, I'm very new to pig. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a [custom UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/udf.html) which does the conversion
(e.g: see `CurrentTime()` [implementation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/CurrentTime.java)). Alternatively you may check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751402) on a similar topic for workarounds.
If you are on AWS, then use their [DATE_TIME](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Elastic-MapReduce/2730) UDF.

Comment: I ended up using your workaround in your answer on the similar topic. It seems odd that there isn't an easier way. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and I didn't want to use a custom UDF as described in the other answer. I am pretty new with Pig but it seems a pretty basic operation to justify the need of an UDF. This command works great for me:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToString(yourdatetimeobject, 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssz') AS yourfieldname;
```

You can select the format you want by looking at the [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)