# What format of date is expected for GetYear() in Pig

Tags: date, apache-pig

I'm trying to use Date functions built into pig.
The input file contains date in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` format.
I'm trying to use the following code:

```
row = foreach log generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL (pattern) AS (date_time : datetime, other columns);

final_data = foreach row {
  yyyy = (chararray)GetYear(date_time);
  mm = (chararray)GetMonth(date_time);
  dd = (chararray)GetDay(date_time);
  hh = (chararray)GetHour(date_time);
  mi = (chararray)GetMinute(date_time);
  ss = (chararray)GetSecond(date_time);
  generate CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(yyyy, '-'), CONCAT(mm, '-')),dd) as myDate;
  }
```

but I get an error:

```
 ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias final_data. Backend error : java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.joda.time.DateTime
```

I'm trying to use workaround from: [Formatting Date in Generate Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749851/formatting-date-in-generate-statement/16751402#16751402)

What format is expected?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#regex-extract-all) takes a string and returns a tuple with the extracted strings, i.e you can't extract into to `DateTime` fields.
You may use the [ToDate](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date) UDF on the date string you loaded: 
E.g:

```
cat data.txt
2014-03-11 13:44:11
2014-02-22 10:44:11

A = load 'data.txt' as (in:chararray);
B = foreach A generate ToDate(in,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as (dt:DateTime);
C = foreach B {
      year = (chararray)GetYear(dt);
      month = (chararray)GetMonth(dt);
      day = (chararray)GetDay(dt);
      generate CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(year, ''), CONCAT(month, '-')),day) as myDate;
};
dump M;
(2014-3-11)
(2014-2-22)
```